# Como puedo trazar una linea horizontal en Chart.js con un sólo número?

Tags: chart.js

Es posible trazar una línea horizontal en chart.js con un sólo dato? en mi gráfica tengo el rendimeinto de los trabajadores y quiero sacar la media y mostrarlo en una linea horizontal, para que se vea en que número cae, porque una manera de hacerlo es punto por punto en un arreglo calculado la media y repitiendo, pero si alguien ha hecho esto antes me gustaría ver cómo lo hizo... éste es mi gráfico:

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');   

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',

        data: {
            
            labels: ['Juan', 'Manuel', 'Martha', 'Abril'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Rendimiento',
                lineTension:0,
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data:[20,30, 40, 50]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        suggestedMin: 0,
                        suggestedMax: 100,
                        stepSize: 5
                    }
                }]
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Trabajadores'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un segundo dataset.

Supongamos que asignas tu array de nombres a una variable llamada `usuarios`:

```
const usuarios = ['Juan', 'Manuel', 'Martha', 'Abril'];
```

Y también utilizas una función para calcular la media con los datos y asginas dicho valor a una variable llamada `media`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es agregar a `data.datasets` otro objeto:

```
datasets: [{
      label: 'Rendimiento',
      lineTension:0,
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data:[20,30, 40, 50]
  },
  {
    label: 'Media',//Este es el nombre en la leyenda
    fill: false, //Esto hace que no se rellene el area debajo de la línea
    radius: 0,//Esto hace que no se vean puntos para cada dato
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    pointHitRadius: 0,//Esto evita que el tooltip aparezca cuando se pase el cursor encima de la línea
    data: usuarios.map( label=>(media))//Este map crea un array del tamaño de usuarios con el valor que especifiques para la variable media
}]
```

Espero que te sirva, no es la solución más elegante, pero funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias, así lo haré, gracias por tu aporte